# Override text in XML with lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

Say I have an XML file and I want to edit parts of it. The following does not work, probably because I am editing a copy of a child.

```
from lxml import etree as et

tree = et.parse(p_my_xml)    
root = tree.getroot()      

for child in root:
  for entry in child.getchildren():

    first_part  = entry.getchildren()[1].text
    second_part = entry.getchildren()[2].text

    if first_part == 'some_condition'
        second_part = 'something_else'

tree.write(p_my_xml, pretty_print=True)
```

How can I correctly modify parts of the XML so that the changes are done in the tree?

Comment: Strings are **immutable**, so even if `getchildren` does give you a copy (I don't know either way, although I suspect not) this was never going to work. Try assigning back to the `text` attribute, i.e. using `second_part = entry.getchildren()[2]` and then `second_part.text = 'something_else'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the reference to the element and [reset the text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983325/771848):

```
second_elm = entry.getchildren()[2]
if first_part == 'some_condition'
    second_elm.text = 'something_else'
```

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, any XML transformation, styling, re-formatting, and re-structuring can be adequately and even efficiently handled with [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), the declarative programming language used for XML manipulation. And Python's lxml module maintains an XSLT processor.

See below generalized example using OP's needs:

**Original XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>    
    <child>
        <entry1>some text</entry1>
        <entry2>other text</entry2>        
    </child>
    <child>
        <entry1>some text</entry1>
        <entry2>other text</entry2>        
    </child>
</root>
```

**XSLT Script**

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 

<xsl:template match="root">
<root>
    <xsl:for-each select="//child">
        <child>
            <xsl:copy-of select="entry1"/>
            <xsl:if test="entry1='some text'">
                <entry2>some new text</entry2>
            </xsl:if>
        </child>
    </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python Script**

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

dom = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'Original.xml'))
xslt = ET.parse(os.path.join(cd, 'XSLTScript.xsl'))
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)

xmlfile = open(os.path.join(cd, 'Final.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Final XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <child>
    <entry1>some text</entry1>
    <entry2>some new text</entry2>
  </child>
  <child>
    <entry1>some text</entry1>
    <entry2>some new text</entry2>
  </child>
</root>
```

While the above may seem too involved and not a Pythonic one-liner, please note there may be an occasion where you require a complex, intricate XML restructuring where you can leverage XSLT's recursive, template formatting language and not run complex iteration loops in object-oriented programming (Python, PHP, Java, C#, etc).

Comment: Great to know. Thanks @Parfait!